# save sqlite database android after application overwrite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, restore

My question is that I want to restore my application's sqlite database after I overwrite the same app on my device. I don't like to add settings again and again on start up of my app.

So is it possible in android to save the database somewhere from  which I can again restore it ?

I have searched for more than hours on Google and SO but couldnt ind any solution.

EDIT: Its not a fixed database. So I can't store it in Assets Folder. It is editable by user but by default it should carry the last edited values(values before the app overwrite).

Comment: Question not very clear. Databases do not get removed when updating apps so I don't see why you need to restore it from somewhere after doing so.

Comment: If you just update your app using the same key for signing, the database should still exist, afaik. Maybe when opening your databasse after overwriting your onUpdate() clears the database? - just a thought, may be false...

Comment: @Kuffs- I am completely removing my app ad then again installing..so I lost my sqlite database every time..I need to restore that.

Comment: some of the tutorials I have seen create a new database each time the app is installed.  Make sure your 'create database' method doesn't do that, otherwise, Kuffs has your answer

Comment: @Martze- Yes, you r right. But I am not updating my app. I am overwriting it by first completely removing it. That's the problem.

Comment: @Martin- I think I got ur answer, but then also can u plz elaborate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method I find very helpful:

```
public static void movedb(File srcdb, File destdb)
{
    try 
    {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()) 
        {                 
            if (srcdb.exists()) 
            {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(srcdb).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destdb).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();                    
            }
            else
            {
                //ERROR: "Database file references are incorrect"                    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //ERROR: "Cannot write to file"
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //ERROR: e.getMessage()
    }
}
```

Then I just call

```
movedb(this, new File(<context>.getDatabasePath("...your DB name...")), new File("... your location ..."));
```

To back up, and then to restore:

```
movedb(this, new File("... your location ..."), new File(<context>.getDatabasePath("...your DB name...")));
```

Comment: But I wonder how will I have srcdb file if I uninstall my app ? I don't have exact idea about this. Thanks for reply.

Comment: You can use this code to make a copy of your database (in a file in your external storage directory) before you uninstall. Then when you reinstall you can restore the data base.

Comment: And the data gets store on SD Card. Right ??

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon how do i set the file location when creating a backup? As in what will that value be since I don't know how the directory structure on my phone is

Comment: The file location is a directory you know to exist on the device. You can check what directories are on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() by printing it to your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ORMLite and, apart from storing the database in the external public directory, after I restore the file to the database directory, I have to re-instantiate the `DatabaseHelper` singleton and create a new one.

Here is my version, omitting every try/catch block for the sake of simplicitiy:

```
public boolean restoreBackup(Context context){

    String databasePath = "data/data/my.package.name/databases/myDatabase.sqlite";
    String backUpPath = context.getDatabaseDir("myDatabase.sqlite");

    // Copies back-up to database directory
    new File(databasePath).delete();
    FileInputStream streemToBackUp = new FileInputStream(new File(backUpPath));
    OutputStream streamToDatabaseFile = new FileOutputStream(databasePath);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = streamToBackUp.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        streamToDatabaseFile.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    streamToDatabaseFile.flush();
    streamToDatabaseFile.close();
    streamToBackUp.close();

    // Re-instantiate DatabasHelper singleton
    DatabaseHelper.closeHelper();
}
```

The body of `closeHelper()` is as follows:

```
public static void closeHelper() {
    helper.close();
}

@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();
    myDao = null; // Set to null every day you have
    helper = null; // Set to null the singleton instance of the helper
}
```

This will work as long as you don't use *OpenHelperManager* class to instantiate the helper, and always use `getHelper()` whenever you need the database instead of storing the instance returned.